# Building a decision tree system to help spec out a system

Tags: expert-system, decision-tree

I'm looking into a way to build a system that will help our sales team spec a product.
The ideal system would ask some base questions which is common amongst all products. Further questions would then branch from these answers. From what I can figure this is essentially a big decision tree/expert system I've been asked to build.

I wondered if anyone has had experience in building such a system and can provide some reference or can recommend a framework/software to support such a system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the answers to questions as values of attributes and then build a decision tree based on these attributes to classify the products. Is this the sort of situation your in?

If so, what are you looking for? Algorithms? Take a look at things like ID3, it is a decision tree algorithm which could work for a situation like yours. I'm not familiar with any specific frameworks/software for decision trees. Let me know if there is any more details you can give about what sort of help you need.